# Postman Form-Data and x-www-form-encoded return null data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, express, cart

When I `POST` with `Content_Type` set to raw/JSON, the response is not null. But when I try to `POST` data with `Content_Type` set to form-data, the response returned as null. How can I solve this?

[Postman Screenshot with FormData](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xy2vm.png)

But when I try as raw data / JSON it's okay:

[Postman Screenshot with JSON Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZT6z6.png)

For raw-data my content-type is :

```
multipart/form-data; boundary=<calculated when request is sent>
```

and my cors settings are :

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");
  if (req.method === "OPTIONS") {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "PUT, POST, PATCH, DELETE, GET");
    return res.status(200).json({});
  }
  next();
});
```

and my post router like that:

```
router.post("/", upload.single("productImage"), (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req.file);
  Category.findById(req.body.categoryID)
    .then((category) => {
      if (!category) {
        return res.status(404).json({
          message: "Category not found",
          category: category,
        });
      }

      //
      const product = new Product({
        _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
        name: req.body.name,
        price: req.body.price,
        quantity: req.body.quantity,
        category: req.body.categoryID,
      });
      return product.save();
    })
    .then((result) => {
      console.log(result);
      res.status(201).json({
        message: "Object created succesfully",
        product: {
          id: result._id,
          name: result.name,
          price: result.price,
          quantity: result.quantity,
          category: result.category,
        },
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err), res.status(500).json({ error: err });
    });
});
```

The error is :

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error
[ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the
 client
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: were you able to solve the problem? Even i have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

You write the var in the wrong way in the form-data example: The right way **categoryID** not **category**.